# Longest Common Substring in a big text

Tags: java

i have this assignment for school which ask us to write code to find the longest common Substring. I have done that, but it only works with text that are not so big and it is being asked to find the common substring for Moby Dick and War And Peace. If you could point me in the right direction of what i'm doing wrong, i would appreciate it. The compiler is complaining that the error is in the substring method of the MyString class when i call it to create the SuffixArray but idk why its saying its too big, giving me the outofmemory

```
package datastructuresone;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


 class SuffixArray
 {

private final MyString[] suffixes;
private final int N;

public SuffixArray(String s)
{
    N = s.length();
    MyString snew = new MyString(s);
    suffixes = new MyString[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        suffixes[i] = snew.substring(i);
    }
    Arrays.sort(suffixes);
}

public int length()
{
    return N;
}

public int index(int i)
{
    return N - suffixes[i].length();
}

public MyString select(int i)
{
    return suffixes[i];
}

// length of longest common prefix of s and t
private static int lcp(MyString s, MyString t)
{
    int N = Math.min(s.length(), t.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (s.charAt(i) != t.charAt(i))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return N;
}

// longest common prefix of suffixes(i) and suffixes(i-1)
public int lcp(int i)
{
    return lcp(suffixes[i], suffixes[i - 1]);
}

// longest common prefix of suffixes(i) and suffixes(j)
public int lcp(int i, int j)
{
    return lcp(suffixes[i], suffixes[j]);

}
}

public class DataStructuresOne
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner in1 = new Scanner(new File("./build/classes/WarAndPeace.txt"));
    Scanner in2 = new Scanner(new File("./build/classes/MobyDick.txt"));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();

    while (in1.hasNextLine())
    {
        sb.append(in1.nextLine());

    }
    while (in2.hasNextLine())
    {
        sb1.append(in2.nextLine());
    }

    String text1 = sb.toString().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    String text2 = sb1.toString().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

    int N1 = text1.length();
    int N2 = text2.length();

    SuffixArray sa = new SuffixArray(text1 + "#" + text2);
    int N = sa.length();

    String substring = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {

        // adjacent suffixes both from second text string
        if (sa.select(i).length() <= N2 && sa.select(i - 1).length() <= N2)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // adjacent suffixes both from first text string
        if (sa.select(i).length() > N2 + 1 && sa.select(i - 1).length() > N2 + 1)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // check if adjacent suffixes longer common substring
        int length = sa.lcp(i);
        if (length > substring.length())
        {
            substring = sa.select(i).toString().substring(0, length);
            System.out.println(substring + " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The length of the substring " + substring.length() + "length on    first N " + N1 + " length of Second N " + N2
            + "The length of the array sa: " + N);
   System.out.println("'" + substring + "'");

   final class MyString implements Comparable<MyString>
{

public MyString(String str)
{
    offset = 0;
    len = str.length();
    arr = str.toCharArray();
}

public int length()
{
    return len;
}

public char charAt(int idx)
{
    return arr[ idx + offset];
}

public int compareTo(MyString other)
{
    int myEnd = offset + len;
    int yourEnd = other.offset + other.len;
    int i = offset, j = other.offset;

    for (; i < myEnd && j < yourEnd; i++, j++)
    {
        if (arr[ i] != arr[ j])
        {
            return arr[ i] - arr[ j];
        }
    }

    // reached end.  Who got there first?
    if (i == myEnd && j == yourEnd)
    {
        return 0;   // identical strings
    }
    if (i == myEnd)
    {
        return -1;
    } else
    {
        return +1;
    }
}


public MyString substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
{
    return new MyString(arr, beginIndex + offset, endIndex - beginIndex);
}

public MyString substring(int beginIndex)
{
    return substring(beginIndex, offset + len);
}

public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    return (other instanceof MyString) && compareTo((MyString) other) == 0;
}

public String toString()
{
    return new String(arr, offset, len);
}

private MyString(char[] a, int of, int ln)
{
    arr = a;
    offset = of;
    len = ln;
}
private char[] arr;
private int offset;
private int len;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    suffixes[i] = snew.substring(i);
}
```

You are trying to store, not only the entire long string, but the entire string - 1 letter, and the entire string - 2 letters, etc.  All of these are stored separately.

If your String were only 10 letters, you would be storing a total of 55 characters worth in 10 different string.

At 1000 characters, you are storing 500500 characters total.

More generally, you are having to handle, length*(length+1)/2 characters.

---

Just for fun, I don't know how many characters are in War and Peace, but with a page count around 1250, a typical words/page estimate being 250, and the average word being about 5 characters long, comes to:

(1250 * 250 * 5)*(1250 * 250 * 5 + 1)/2 = 1.2207039 * 10^12 characters.

The size of a char in memory being 2 bytes, so you're looking at about 2.22 TB in size (compared to 1.49 MB for just the text of the novel).

Answer (score 1):

I count at least 3 copies of both texts in the first few lines of the code. Here's a few ideas

- convert the spaces as you read each line in--not after they are huge strings. Don't forget the case of spaces at the front and end of lines.
- build your MyString class using StringBuilder as the base instead of String. Do all the looking inside the StringBuilder with its native methods, if you can.
- don't extract strings any more than you have to.

Look up the -Xmx java runtime option and set the heap space large than the default. You'll have to google this as I don't have it memorized. Just notice that -Xmx=1024M needs that M at the end. (Look at the file size to see how big the two books are.)

Answer (score 0):

When you construct MyString, you call `arr = str.toCharArray();` which makes a new copy of the string's character data. But in Java, a string is immutable - so why not store a reference to the string instead of a copy of its data?

You construct every suffix at once, but you only refer to one (well, two) at a time. If you recode your solution to only reference the suffixes it currently cares about, and construct them only when it needs them (and lose a reference to them afterwards), they can be garbage collected by Java. This will make running out of memory less likely. Compare the memory overhead of storing 2 strings to storing hundreds of thousands of strings :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this program in Scala. Maybe you can translate it to Java.

```
class MyString private (private val string: String, startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int) extends Comparable[MyString] {
  def this(string: String) = this(string, 0, string.length)
  def length() = endIndex-startIndex
  def charAt(i: Int) = {
    if(i >= length) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
    string.charAt(startIndex + i)
  }
  def substring(start: Int, end: Int): MyString = {
    if(start < 0 || end > length || end < start) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
    new MyString(string, startIndex + start, startIndex + end)
  }
  def substring(start: Int): MyString = substring(start, length)
  def longestCommonSubstring(other: MyString): MyString = {
    var index = 0
    val len = math.min(length, other.length)
    while(index < len && charAt(index) == other.charAt(index)) index += 1
    substring(0, index)
  }
  def compareTo(other: MyString): Int = {
    val len = math.min(length, other.length)
    for(i <- 0 until len) {
      if(charAt(i) > other.charAt(i)) return 1
      if(charAt(i) < other.charAt(i)) return -1
    }
    length-other.length
  }
  def >(other: MyString) = compareTo(other) > 0
  def <(other: MyString) = compareTo(other) < 0
  override def equals(other: Any) = other.isInstanceOf[MyString] && compareTo(other.asInstanceOf[MyString]) == 0
  override def toString() = "\"" + string.substring(startIndex, endIndex) + "\""
}

def readFile(name: String) = new MyString(io.Source.fromFile(name).getLines.mkString(" ").replaceAll("\\s+", " "))
def makeList(str: MyString) = (0 until str.length).map(i => str.substring(i)).toIndexedSeq

val string1 = readFile("WarAndPeace.txt")
val string2 = readFile("MobyDick.txt")

val (list1, list2) = (makeList(string1).sorted, makeList(string2).sorted)

var longestMatch = new MyString("")
var (index1, index2) = (0,0)
while(index1 < list1.size && index2 < list2.size) {
  val lcs = list1(index1).longestCommonSubstring(list2(index2)) 
  if(lcs.length > longestMatch.length) longestMatch = lcs
  if(list1(index1) < list2(index2)) index1 += 1
  else index2 += 1
}

println(longestMatch)
```