# In a git diff, distinguish a delete from a move

Tags: git, string-matching, git-diff

(I found [a related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504560/detecting-copied-or-similar-text-blocks). It makes no mention of Git. There's also a tool called [Copy Paste Detector](https://pmd.github.io/#about), but it's specific to code, not plain text (and also not git-aware).)

I keep a knowledge base as a set of plain markdown (plain text) files, and track changes to it in git.

Suppose the git diff shows a missing hunk of text. It might be that I deleted it, or it might be that I moved it (in the same file, or to another).

I wish I had some easy way of knowing which. Currently I grep the whole knowledge base for substrings from the deletion. If I don't find one, I'll grep for a few more. I should probably fuzzy grep -- but even then it still might not work, because maybe I moved most of the text but not the specific substring I fuzzy-grepped for.

Better would be a git-aware tool that looks for fuzzy matches between deletions and insertions. Ideally one that could ignore whitespace.

Does such a thing exist? Or if not, could it be cobbled together without a massive amount of work?

Comment: Git's `git blame` does actually try to solve this problem, to some extent. The main issue is that you'd have to be looking at the file the code moved *to*, and it would then find the file that the code came *from*. It doesn't (currently) have the ability to work the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

For individual hunks of code, I don't know of any way to do what you're asking.  (For files as a whole, git *does* calculate a "similarity" value if it sees a deletion at one path and a new file at another path, and by default if that values is high enough - per a configurable threshold - then it reports the file as "renamed".  But that won't really help with your use case.)

If you frequently need to know this kind of thing after the fact, then I would consider recording what was done in the commit message or a commit note.  ("Moved XXXX from /file1 to /file2" or "Deleted YYYY from /file3")